# LNK2019 error when trying to use array struct?

Tags: arrays, c, winapi, struct, compiler-errors

I am trying to contain coordinates for rectangles in order to interact with them and I have made two structs for that a vec2 for x and y and a Field with two points start and end. if I now try to use it I get the error :

Main.obj : error LNK2019: Reference to unresolved extern Symbol "_map" in function "_wWinMain@16".

The code using it:

```
Field map[];

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow) 
{
    //win32 stuff
    for (int i = 0, z = 0; i < rowLength; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < (int)(rowLength * 0.9); j++)
        {
            Field temp = { {(int)((startPos.x + 150 * j) * scale), (int)((startPos.y + 150 * i) * scale)}, 
                         {(int)(((startPos.x + 145) + 150 * j) * scale), (int)(((startPos.y + 145) + 150 * i) * scale)} };
            map[z] = temp;
            z++;
        }
    }
    //more win32 stuff
}
```

The struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    float x;
    float y;
}vec2;

typedef struct
{
    vec2 startPos;
    vec2 endPos;
}Field;
```

If i try giving the array length this error occurs:

Main.c(13): error C2057: Constant expression expected

Main.c(13): error C2466: Assignment of array with constant size 0 not possible.

Comment: *If i try giving the array length*. Please show that code.

Comment: @kaylum i simply write Field map[rows * (int)(rows * 0.9)]

Comment: You can't do it that way. Microsoft compilers don't support Variable Length Arrays. You need to use a constant size for the array or use dynamic memory allocation via `malloc` and friends.

Comment: I thought it would work bc have declared rows to be a constant but if that doesnt work I will look into malloc and see what i can do

Answer (score 2):

As with @kaylum said,Microsoft compilers don't support Variable Length Arrays.
Try the following code, if it is known on compile stage:

```
const int rowLength = 10;
Field map[rowLength];
```

otherwise, use malloc in runtime:

```
Field* map = (Field*)malloc(rowLength * sizeof(Field));
```